# What is the complexity when multiplying an mxn matrix by an nxm matrix?

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

what is the matrix complexity when you multiply an mxn matrix by nxm matrix?
my guess is that it will be m^2 since it would result to an m by m matrix, but im not too sure

all help would be much appreciated

Comment: With the naive algorithm or with better algorithms? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Algorithms_for_efficient_matrix_multiplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing the dot product of two length $n$ vectors requires $2n$ operations.  In your case, you compute a dot product of two length $n$ vectors for each entry in the result.  A total of $m^2 \cot 2n$ operations.  The the operation count is $2m^2n$.

You can generalize this idea for an $n\times m$ matrix multiplied by a $m\times p$ matrix to get an operation count of $2mnp$

Comment: This is of course using the naive matrix multiplication method.